# Call custom Umbraco targets during TFS build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, umbraco

Is there a way to trigger the custom deployment targets through a TFS build? We are using TFS 2015 (with VS 2015, git repository) and I started with a Visual Studio build definition template, but the custom targets (UmbracoCms.targets) do not get triggered so the umbraco, umbraco_client, and other folders do not get collected in the deployment to the artifacts folder.

I have gotten the publish profiles from within Visual Studio to work correctly multiple times before.

Specifically, here is my configuration:

- Solution: $(SolutionPath)
- MSBuild Arguments: `/p:OutDir=$(build.stagingDirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true`
- Platform: $(BuildPlatform)
- Configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
- Clean: No
- Restore NuGet: No
- VS Version: 2015

*Cross posted on [our.umbraco.com](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/78979-tfs-build-trigger-umbraco-copy-targets)*

Comment: How did you deploy Umbraco targets locally?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I worked off of the [readme](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/master-v7/build/NuSpecs/tools/Readme.txt) from the NuGet install, but essentially created a filesystem publish profile, that triggered the targets. Doing a local build didn't require the targets because the VS excluded folders were already visible to IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more experimenting I found that the below MSBuild parameters published the site as expected (specifically the `PublishProfile` parameter). I still consider this non-ideal since part of my goal was to create a system where deploying to staging (or production) couldn't be done from Visual Studio without a lot of work and would normally have to go through TFS (for the audit trail). Using the built in publish profiles fundamentally requires the Visual Studio setup I was trying to avoid but I haven't found any alternatives.

`/p:OutDir=$(build.stagingDirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Intranet.pubxml`